# Sign of the limit of $x^β (-\log x)^α$ as $x \to 0^+$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, limits-without-lhopital

My analysis book [1] explains that
$$
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{(\log_a x)^α}{x^β} = 0
$$
for $β > 0$, and that by replacing $x = 1/y$ we get
$$
\lim_{y \to 0^+}y^β(-\log_a y)^α = 0.\tag{*}\label{*}
$$
Then it asks why it would be wrong to write $(\log_a y)$ instead of $(-\log_a y)$.

My reasoning was, well, I'd miss a factor $(-1)^α$, which changes the sign of the expression when $α$ is odd. Maybe I can divide both sides by $(-1)^α$ and, noting that as $y \to 0^+$

- $y^β$ is positive and
- $(\log_a y)^α$ is positive for even $α$, negative for odd $α$,

I'd get
$$
\lim_{y \to 0^+}y^β(\log_a y)^α =
\begin{cases}
  0^+\cdot 1 = 0^+ & \text{for even $α$}\\
  0^-\cdot -1 = 0^+ & \text{for odd $α$}
\end{cases}
$$
and there I go, wrong result: the sign is flipped for odd $α$, and I don't know what it should be for even values of $α$. Where am I wrong?

**Edit:** I was wrong in taking for granted that $α$ is integer, which it is not, so my handling of $(-1)^α$ is wrong (thanks geetha290krm).

Still, is there an answer to the question the book poses in terms of effects of the minus sign on the expression? The fact that they asked it makes me wonder what else there is to be seen other than that $\log(1/y) = -\log y$.

---

1 Bramanti, Pagani, Salsa; *Analisi 1* (2014), p. 132

Comment: Is it mentioned that $\alpha, \beta$ are integers?

Comment: @geetha290krm I believe they're real. It says so for another equation a bit earlier, and I think it still holds for the equations in the question, for which it just specifies $β > 0, \forall α$.

Comment: So you have invented the concept of even and odd real numbers!

Comment: Also, $(-1)^{\alpha}$ is not well defined for real numbers $\alpha$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Geee! In my defense, I took for granted that $α was integer until you asked, then I'm a bit ashamed that I didn't make the connection…

Answer (score 1):

Since eq. $(\text{*})$ has to hold for all real $α$, the term which is raised to the power of $α$ can't be negative, and the minus sign ensures that it is not.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it has nothing to do with odd/even. When you’re  substituting $y$ in place of $x$ in the part $\log_ax$, what you are actually doing is
$$\log_ax=\log_a\frac1y=\log_ay^{-1}=-\log_ay$$

And that’s where the minus sign comes from.

Comment: No doubt about this, but I was wondering if there was an explanation that took into consideration the effect of omitting that minus sign on the expression. And after my reasoning I've sort of convinced myself of something wrong and I'd like to know my mistake.